# element proofs difficulty

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I just started practicing element proofs and I'm stuck trying to the solve a transitive property of a subset.
For all sets A,B, and C.  If $A \subseteq B$ and $A \subseteq C,$  then $A \subseteq B \cap C$

Comment: have you tried drawing a diagram? Let $x \in A$ and try with it.

Comment: hint: the definition of the intersection of two sets $S\cap S’=\{x| x\in S \land x\in S’\}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just note that:

$$x \in A \implies x \in B \text{ and } x \in C \implies x \in B\cap C$$

With the first implication being the hypothesis.

Comment: So since $A \subseteq B and X \in A then X \in B.  And since A \subseteq C and X \in C then X \in C$   ? right?

Comment: Right, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

By definition $A\cap B = \{x: x\in A \land x\in B\}$, and $B \cap C =\{x:x\in B \land x \in C\}$

---

$A\cap B = A$ if and only if $A \subseteq B$

**Proof**: Suppose $A\subseteq B$, then for every $x\in A$, $x\in B$ as well. $A \subseteq A\cap B$. Certainly $A\cap B \subseteq A$, because by definition $x\in A\cap B$ implies $x\in A$ in particular. $A\cap B =A$.

Suppose $A\cap B = A$, then every $x\in A$ is also an element of $A\cap B$ and by definition is element of $A$ and $B$, in particular $B$. $A\subseteq B$.

The above holds for arbitrary sets, not necessarily just $A$ and $B$.

---

$(A\cap B)\cap C = A\cap (B\cap C)$

**Proof**: $(A\cap B)\cap C = \{x: x\in (A\cap B)\land x\in C\}= \{x: (x\in A \land x\in B) \land x\in C\}=\{x:x\in A \land(x\in B\land x\in C)\}=\{x:x\in A \land (x\in B\cap C)\}=A\cap(B\cap C)$

because $(P\land Q)\land R \equiv P\land (Q\land R)$

---

Since it is given that $A\subseteq B$, $A\cap B = A$.

We have also that $A \subseteq C$, this implies $(A \cap B) \cap C = A \cap C = A$, but $(A\cap B) \cap C = A \cap (B\cap C)$, thus $A\cap (B\cap C) =A$ and $A \subseteq B\cap C$.